# Vagrant was unable to mount VirtualBox shared folders error

Tags: laravel, plugins, vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

This is my error and I couldn't fix it. I need help, my virtual box is on the lastest version.

[image: Check the error here]

The list of vagrant plugins:

[image: The list of vagrant plugins]

I tried to update them but every time I restart my vagran, they get the default version. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the time of writing this, the latest version of VirtualBox (5.1.16) on Windows is having problems mounting any drives from Vagrant, and the only solution so far is to wait for an update that resolves this, or manually downgrade VirtualBox to 5.1.14.

There's more information about other people having similar problems in this GitHub issue: https://github.com/laravel/homestead/issues/510

Comment: YES IT WORKS NOW! I downgraded my virtual box  to 5.1.14 and now it works. Thank you .. I've spent my 3 days to fix this problem and finally resolved thank you so much!

Comment: Wow I've been struggling with the same issue for the past few days, tried multiple computers and distros. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can update to the 5.1.18 version. It works in this version

Comment: I've not upgraded yet but will keep in my mind thanks